# Is there a Beloved of Chemosh template anywhere?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragonlance

For a while, I am looking for this template, but failed to find one (even unofficial). In a long time ago, `Sean Everette` posts to a message aobut this template in [dragonlance forums](http://www.dragonlanceforums.com/forums/showthread.php?506-The-Beloved-of-Chemosh?s=)

> A template for the Beloved of Chemosh will appear in Holy Orders of the Stars.

but related book have one and a half page of exlanation about the beloved in the form of a letter from Jenna to wizards conclave. No statistics and no further game information.

Is there any source or book that gives that emplate?

Answer (score 1):

I have found [one template](http://books.google.com/books?id=sdxfI1cQh-kC&pg=PT395&lpg=PT395&dq=%22creating+a+beloved+of+chemosh%22&source=bl&ots=AcL5fMOq7c&sig=zsOFesQYoh2ZId6V9IhfutRjjPI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S7OPUZ_7M-3G4AOd3YFI&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA) for it, from something called *Amber and Iron: Dark Disciple, Volume 2*. The production quality seems reasonably high (uses the appropriate terminology, covers all the bases as far as the rules you need to apply a template, and so on), though the beloved does not seem nearly as invincible as the quick blurb I read while researching this suggested they should be.

Comment: But where is the template? This link goes to book review page.

Comment: @FallenAngel Huh, it works for me. Maybe because I was the one who did the search? I don't know. Anyway, it's an Appendix, listed in the Table of Contents, at the very end of the book, just before the ad for other books and the About the Author page. Do a search for "Creating a Beloved of Chemosh."